# Entity Print Content Modification For Views

Tags: 8

I have a views that I am printing to PDF using [Entity Print](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print). The views is a combination of several entities and as such cannot directly utilize the instruction in the ["Modify entity content"](https://www.drupal.org/node/2706755#s-modifying-entity-content) section of the documentation:

> To modify the content of your entity, you
> create a twig template using the 'pdf' view mode name (e.g.
> node--article--pdf.html.twig). In this template you can modify the
> markup as you normally do with other view modes using {{
> content.field_example }} or {{ node.field_example }}.

See screenshot of the view:

[image]
I tried this twig template suggestion `entity-print--views--machine_name--pdf.html` and template variables like `{{ content.field_bright_news }}` (where the name of one of the fields of a referred entity of the view is `field_bright_news`) but that doesn't seem to work except I may be missing something.

Is the stated instruction in the documentation applicable to views as well or it's solely meant for actual entities. If yes, what is the correct template and variable pattern for this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your template suggestion is correct in this case, so {{content.field_bright_news}} may not work.

A few things I can clarify for you are as follows:

{{content.field_bright_news}} - this variable is only available in the template of the content type containing that field, it cannot be used in the view template.

For your quote, it is missing the following:

> By default this module only installs the PDF view mode for Nodes. If you have any custom entities on your Drupal site and want to hide the "View PDF" link on those, you must first create a PDF view mode for the entity type. To do this navigate to "admin / structure / display-modes / view" and click on "Add view mode". In the list click the entity type for which you would like to create the PDF view mode. You'll now be asked to name the view mode, you can name it whatever you like but make sure the machine name is just "pdf", which will be automatically prefixed with the entity name. You can now follow the steps in the previous paragraphs for your custom entity.

That is, you must create a display mode for that content type to have a template suggesting as the form

**node--content_type--display_mode.html.twig**

And that means, **{{content.field_bright_news}}** can be used in the template suggested above.

Comment: You clearly haven't used the module before and my question is not about node, which is what the section of the document referred to. My question is whether or not and how the stated instruction is applicable to views. It has it nuances that's slightly different from the typical theming approach.

Comment: I need a little more clarification.
Is what you need to use is the field_bright_news of each node in the view?

Comment: The view has fields from several entities's, including custom content type, drupal commerce entities including order, order item and invoice.

Comment: your template suggestion is come from the line 75 of this file: **entity_print/src/PrintBuilder.php**. And the variable **content** is come from line #77 `'#content' => $content` with `$content = $renderer->render([$entity]);`. So if you want to use `{{ content. child_variable }}` , you need to dump that variable to check which one can be use. Does it have **{{content.field_bright_news}}**?

Comment: The documentation mentioned using `node--article--pdf.html.twig` for the pdf view mode of the content type 'article', then you can now position the fields as required in the template. So my first requirement to determine the Views equivalent of `node--article--pdf.html.twig`, after that I can start checking for available variables to the suggestion.

Comment: Could you please attached the screen shoot  of your view config? I know that you are misunderstanding about theming and template suggestion in your case.

Comment: If you are not rendering the Content in the view, but using fields, it won't pick up this template. You'd have to use the Content style and the PDF view mode which is what I think the docs are saying.

Comment: @mr.Thi I updated the question to include a screenshot of the view. Kelvin, I get, was just thinking perhaps there is a way to (not indicated in the doc) that it could be used for a view. If not, what do you think is the possible app[roach to converting this view to a content type that allows passing value through the url as done via contextual filter of view (pre-populate ?). thanks.